# How to call POST webservice in Native iOS code using Plugin - Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, post, phonegap-plugins, xcode8

I am trying to create a Hybrid iOS project using Phonegap. I have got the **www** folder contents (html, js, css and all required data). I just wanted to build iOS container and put the **www** contents into it. It is done.

Now I want to call a POST web service method (should pass image and text contents), written in iOS native code from one of the html page. I have followed few links to implement the plugin, but nothing seems to be working and I couldn't figure it out what am I missing.

Given below the links which I have followed:

http://www.jkrause.io/blog/2013/07/25/example-of-a-native-ios-plugin-for-using-phonegap-3/
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html
 and some videos as well.

Comment: "nothing seems to be working" - may we see your code so far? It is hard for readers to give you feedback without seeing your work.

Comment: Please check the steps in http://www.jkrause.io/blog/2013/07/25/example-of-a-native-ios-plugin-for-using-phonegap-3/ , this is what I have followed last. It would be really helpful if I get a step by step instructions to implement this.